# ROR: How to get and compare just the dates of datetimes using SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sqlite, date, datetime

I want to be able to list any 'events' in my database which occur on the same date as another event being creating in my method.
The column I want to compare is '`starts_at`' and is a `DateTime`.
How can I just compare the date that events occured on instead of both date and time?

I need to add the query to this where call:

```
events = Event.where(location_id: location.id)
```

I already have a date object `date` to compare to, I just don't know how I can get just the date part of the events already in the database?

is it something along the lines of date(starts_at:)?

```
events = Event.where(location_id: location.id, date(starts_at:): date)
```

I am using sqlite database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works with your DB or not:

```
events = Event.where(location_id: location.id).where("DATE(starts_at) = ?", date)
```

OR, compare in datetime as per active record:

```
events = Event.where(location_id: location.id,starts_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
```